# How to get sharepoint site name based on GUID?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, guid

Is there a way to get a sharepoint site's name by using the site guid?

Comment: Here's a reference list: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1660.sharepoint-feature-guid-and-name-mapping-en-us.aspx

Comment: Thanks but it is not what I am asking.  I have a set of site guid, and I would like to retrieve the site name based on the guid.

Comment: It would help to have a little more information as to how you are attempting to access that information. Are you using the SharePoint Client Object Model, or are you using the server-side SharePoint library? What kind of project are you building that requires the information?

Comment: Are you referring to the SPSite (Site Collection) or SPWeb (Web Site) - both have a GUID. In fact, almost every object in SharePoint has an associated GUID.

Answer (score 0):

Using SP object model:

```
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteId))
 {
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(webId))
    {
       string title = web.Title;
     }
 }
```

For the rest you can use CAML Query.
EX CAML Query:

```
<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='UniqueId'/><Value Type='Guid'>{0}</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>
```